# How to reserve unpush commit

Tags: git, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

i have bunch of commit but haven't push yet, now i want to remove those commit from my branch, how to do it.
[image: my sourcetree]

I'm using sourcetree

Answer (score 1):

You would need to:

- create a new branch starting from the commit just before the series of commits you are about to push
- [cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) the commits you do not want to push into that new branch
- do [an interactive rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) of your branch, dropping any commit you do not want.

Then you can push your current branch.